# How to move node app from javascript to typescript gradually

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a javascript node application that is quiet big now and I want to switch to typescript to accelerate the development and better maintain the code. I installed typescript with `node` and `mocha` types with the commands

```
npm i typescript
npm i @types/node
npm i @types/mocha
```

I use a `tsconfig.json` file which is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I added the `"tsc": "tsc"` script in the `package.json` to compile the code using the `npm run tsc` command.

Here is my project architecture:

```
- dist // created at compile time
- src
--- server.ts
--- configs
----- config.js
--- // other subdirectories
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
```

When I compile the code, it creates a `dist` folder that only contains the compiled `server.ts` file, the only file I renamed to `.ts`. So when I launch the compiled app with `node dist/server.js` all the other files are missing and the app crashes.

My question is: do I have to switch the whole application to typescript, renaming every file to `.ts` and changing imports or is there a way I can do it gradually and keep some javascript files?

Comment: Check out the `allowJs` option and other advice discussed in the [Migrating from JavaScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly :ok_hand:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by Jeff in the comments of my post, here is how you can gradually switch to typescript. Base on the link [Migrating from javascript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) he provided, here is how I managed to make it work.

I changed the `tsconfig.json` file to:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true, // <-- option to allow js files as input in the ts compiler
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I also changed the `package.json` of the project to launch the app and run the tests from the compiled folder (which is `dist` in my case):

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "test": "tsc && ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive ./dist/test",
    "tsc": "tsc",
},
...
```